# "I doing something", "me doing something", "my doing something" as an object

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, objects

Consider the following four sentences:

1. She doesn't like that I talked rudely to her.
2. She doesn't like I talking rudely to her.
3. She doesn't like my talking rudely to her.
4. She doesn't like me talking rudely to her.

My questions:

- Which of those sentences are grammatical?
- I know "that I talked rudely to her" is a noun clause. What is "somebody doing something" technically called when used as an object?